# Optimizing Expo AV for Efficient Video Caching in Flatlist?

Tags: buffering, expo-av

I have a list with infinite video scrolling using Flatlist. I am using the Expo AV package, and everything is working well. However, regardless of whether users watch the videos or not, Expo AV caches the entire video in memory. I would like it so that, unless the user starts playing the video, only a 2-second portion is cached in memory. Once the user initiates playback, the remaining portion should be cached. Your assistance with this matter would be greatly appreciated.